# git: Can I commit and start with the same message as the last commit (NOT amend)

Tags: git

Jira issues are often assigned Issue numbers and titles which have to be included in the commit message - and these strings have to be the same for every commit message in a branch, across multiple commits.

Sometimes these strings are quite lengthy to type out, or inconvenient to copy and paste from Jira's webui.

For convenience I would like to use the same commit message **rather than write out the same Jira issue number and title** over and over again.

As an alternative can I set a default commit message for this branch? (I would like to be able to setup a default message and then edit it.)

I am not intending to copy paste the exact same message, only use the last message as a template.

Those familiar with Jira will know that the tag line or final line of the commit often always has to conform to some predefined syntax *which is **always** the same for every commit on a branch*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
git commit --reuse-message HEAD
```

will reuse the previous commit message.

If you want to be able to edit that message before committing, do

```
git commit --reuse-message HEAD --edit
```

The `-e/--edit` switch will bring up the editor.

Comment: Any way to combine this so git opens the editor to edit the commit message? Think behavior of `git commit`

Comment: Yes, the `-e` switch brings up the editor when you already have a message, like with `-m` or with the command above.

Comment: Thanks that's perfect